# Angular Universal Not Loading styles given in angular.json file

Tags: css, angular, angular-universal

I am using angular universal and everything working fine except my styles are not get applied on application when I hit the urls from postman. In browser it renders styles.

All components css is getting applied but the css written in style.scss is not getting applied.

Here is repo link where you can see all the code.
https://github.com/sudhir-j-sapkal/angular-seo-universal?organization=sudhir-j-sapkal

It is clone of https://github.com/snipcart/angular-seo-universal

Comment: was there a solution for this?